# Alocação dinâmica para struct

Tags: c, memória, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Preciso alocar dinamicamente espaço para uma estrutura, mas não estou conseguido e não sei de meu erro é na hora da declaração ou da alocação, seguem as funções condizentes com a declaração.

Declaração

```
struct {
    char nome[100];
    char rua[100];
    char cidade[100];
    char estado[100];
    unsigned long int cep;
} dados;
```

Alocação

```
void cria_lista(void) {
    dados info;

    info = malloc(sizeof(struct info));
}
```

Realocação

```
void insere(void) {
    int aux;
    int posicao;
    posicao = livre();
    if (posicao == -1) {
        printf("\nEstrutura Cheia!!");
        return;
    }
    if (posicao != 0){
        info = realloc(info,1);
    }
    printf("-- Registro %d:\n", posicao);
    printf("\t Nome: ");
    ler_string(busca.nome, 30);
    aux = busca_nome();
    if (aux != 0)
        strcpy(info[posicao].nome, busca.nome);
    printf("\t Rua: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].rua, 40);
    printf("\t Cidade: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].cidade, 20);
    printf("\t Estado: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].estado, 2);
    printf("\t CEP: ");
    scanf("%lu", &info[posicao].cep);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De cara já dá para ver este erro:

```
malloc(sizeof(struct info));
```

O correto é:

```
malloc(sizeof(dados));
```

Você quer alocar um elemento aí? É isto que está fazendo depois desta mudança. Se quer alocar para mais elementos precisa multiplicar pela quantidade desejada.

```
info = realloc(info, 1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Dynamic.c).

Agora parece estar um pouco pior, porque `info` nem parece existir neste contexto. Se existe, deveria mostrar pra gente. Nem consigo dizer qual deveria ser o certo porque o código apresentado não faz sentido.

---

Tem outras coisas esquisitas como `unsigned int` para CEP. Você vai fazer contas com isto? Se o CEP começar com zero vai saber tratar para mostrar do jeito correto?

Comment: Estava alocando como dados, quando o correto realmente seria como info, obrigado pela observação.

Comment: Acho que você ainda está fazendo confusão. O que pode estar parecendo certo ainda tem erros. Mas não posso garantir sem entender o código todo e sua intenção real. De qualquer forma a solução que você arrumou muda bem o que você estava fazendo. Se você acha que resolveu, ótimo.

Answer (score 0):

Olá resolvi a minha questão da seguinte forma
1 - alterando a declaração para

```
struct end{
    char nome[100];
    char rua[100];
    char cidade[100];
    char estado[100];
    unsigned long int cep;
} *info;
```

2 - fazendo a alocação toda de uma vez

```
void cria_lista(void) {
    int i;
    info = malloc (MAX*sizeof(struct end));
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        info[i].nome[0] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Ainda não é a resposta ideal, mas no momento funciona ...