# Como aumentar dinamicamente o tamanho struct?

Tags: c, array, struct

Como aumentar tamanho da `struct` quando o tamanho atual for atingido?

```
#define TAM_MAX 50;
typedef struct{
char nome[TAM_NOME];            /* nao pode ser vazio*/
char sobrenome[TAM_SOBRENOME];
char telefone[3][TAM_FONE];     /* modelo: '+99 (99) 9 9999 9999' */
char email[3][TAM_EMAIL];       /* 'modelo: a-z . _ 0-9 @ a-z . a-z . a-z' */
} TCONTATO;
TCONTATO agenda[TAM_MAX];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O tamanho da `struct` não é possível. O que parece que está querendo é aumentar o tamanho do *array*. Também não dá dinamicamente, criou, fica daquele tamanho.

O que dá para fazer é alocar no *heap* uma porção de bytes suficiente para armazenar a quantidade de objetos que deseja ([`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc)) e se chegar no limite realocar ([`realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)). Desta forma terá um ponteiro gerado pela função de alocação criando uma indireção.

Já respondi algo a respeito em [Alocação dinâmica para struct](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41692/101), [Erro Segmentation fault (core dumped)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52555/101) e [Problema com alocação dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/132158/101). Também pode ser útil: [Problemas com alocação dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40562/101)

Pode ser útil: [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101). Uma pergunta já foi feita sobre alocação: [Qual a finalidade da função free()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101).

E não há nada errado na declaração da `struct`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Uma coisa que você pode fazer é armazenar apenas ponteiros na sua struct

```
typedef struct{
    char *nome;
    char *sobrenome;
    size_t num_telefones;
    char **telefones;
    size_t num_emails;
    char **emails;
} TCONTATO;
```

Se você fizer isso, vai ser preciso alocar espaço para esses campos separadamente. É mais complicado do que a versão que você faz agora, em que a memória está sempre dentro da struct, mas é mais flexível.

Answer (score -1):

Sua declaração de struct esta incorreta, a forma correta seria:

```
typedef struct myStruct{ //myStruct é o nome da struct declarada
```

A forma mais segura de se aumentar dinamicamente os itens dentro de uma struct é criar essa mesma struct com tipos abstratos de dados(TAD). Não é possível aumentar o tamanho de um item de uma struct se o mesmo item for de um tipo primitivo como int, char, float ou double, para aumenta-lo dinamicamente ele precisa ser um tipo abstrato de dados como uma Pilha, Fila ou Lista, detalhe que tipos abstratos de dados(TAD) fazem parte de um conteúdo um pouco mais avançado da programação em C, notoriamente você precisa dominar com facilidade a linguagem para poder implementa-los.

Comment: O que está errado na declaração?

Comment: Me refiro a declaração de struct para uso em um TAD.

Comment: O typedef dele está correto. Você só precisa fazer `struct myStruct {` quando o tipo da sua struct é recursivo.

Comment: Justamente, uma struct para TAD

Comment: `typedef struct myStruct{
      int value;
      int index;
      struct myStruct *front, *back; //próxima struct e anterior
}Index; //Lista duplamente encadeada`